# Select2 4.0.5 trigger event on Text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

in an earlier version of select2 I was able to fire an event with select2-selecting when typing into the search box. In 4.0.5, with select2:selecting, it seems to not work anymore. Anyone knowing a working solution? I want to send an ajax request to my sever everytime I type into the searchbar of the select2. Like I said in an earlier version that was possible! Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put select2 on a select item in 4.x

https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax

Did it acording to that example and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the html element from input to select. Input worked with older versions of select2 but not with 4.x

old html

```
<input id="groupSelect" name="group_id" type="text" style="max-width: 100%; width: 100%;" required>
```

new html

```
<select id="groupSelect" name="group_id" type="text" style="max-width: 100%; width: 100%;" required></select>
```